# A integer calculation problem whose integrand is $\frac1{A \chi^2+B}$

Tags: calculus, chi-squared

I'm calculating an expectation of the form $$\mathbb E\left[1\over aX+b\right]$$where $X\sim\chi^2_1(0)$ obeys an central chi squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom. The integral formula is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty{x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}\over ax+b}dx$$and I can not solve this integral. Also I tried the [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) but it still offers no solution.

How to calculate this integral? I'm longing toward the answer!

Comment: According to Mathematica, this seems to have a closed form in terms of the complementary error function $\mathrm{erfc}(x):=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty\mathrm e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt$:
$$\mathbb E\!\left[\frac1{aX+b}\right]=\sqrt{\frac\pi{2ab}}\,\mathrm e^{\frac b{2 a}} \mathrm{erfc}\!\left(\sqrt{\frac b{2a}}\right).$$

Comment: @nejimban Can you provide more details about how Mathematica calculating it? I can not derive the exp. by myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mathematica doesn't provide the calculation steps. Have you tried:
1) Changing the variable, e.g., $x=u^2$ in your integral?
2) Integrating by parts?
3) Introducing things like $\mathrm e^{-x/2}=\frac12\int_x^\infty\mathrm e^{-t/2}\,\mathrm dt$ or $\mathrm{erfc}'(x)=-\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\mathrm e^{-x^2}$, using Fubini…?